# ARKit SCNVector3 and extensions not working together

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I have an app that that aims to record the camera's current X,Y,Z coordinates and print them out. It does this properly with the code down below

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, willRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {

        guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }
        let transform = pointOfView.transform
        let CamPosition = SCNVector3(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
        print(CamPosition)
```

I want to truncate the printed output since it's very long. I found this extension to truncate the values.

```
extension Double {
    func truncate(places : Int)-> Double {
        return Double(floor(pow(10.0, Double(places)) * self)/pow(10.0, Double(places)))
    }
}
```

This works if I print something like this:

```
x = 1.123456789
print(x.truncate(places: 2))
```

but will not work if I print it out like this:

```
print(camRotation.truncate(palces:2))
```

The error it gives me says "Value of type 'SCNVector4' has no member 'truncate'"

is this a formatting issue on my end or do SCNVectors just not allow you to use extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Value of type 'SCNVector4' has no member 'truncate'"

`camRotation` is a `SCNVector4`.

Your extension is on `Double`, not `SCNVector4`.

```
          /// Double, not SCNVector4
extension Double {
    func truncate(places : Int)-> Double {
        return Double(floor(pow(10.0, Double(places)) * self)/pow(10.0, Double(places)))
    }
}
```

Extensions work on any type, but `camRotation.truncate(palces:2)` doesn't work, because the type doesn't match.

---

Ok, now on to the actual answer. Currently, your code says

```
let CamPosition = SCNVector3(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
```

Just apply `truncate` to each of the components:

```
let CamPosition = SCNVector3(
    transform.m41.truncate(places: 2),
    transform.m42.truncate(places: 2),
    transform.m43.truncate(places: 2)
)
print(CamPosition)
```

Because these components take in `Float` values, you should also change your extension to this:

```
extension Float {
    func truncate(places: Int) -> Float {
        return Float(floor(pow(10.0, Float(places)) * self)/pow(10.0, Float(places)))
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing! Thank you so much!